# Quelle est la différence entre « La chauve-souris est l’équivalent dans les airs de la souris. » et « Une chauve-souris est […] d’une souris. »?

Tags: sens, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Quelle est la différence entre « La chauve-souris est l’équivalent dans les airs de la souris. » et « Une chauve-souris est l’équivalent dans les airs d’une souris » ?

Et pourquoi disons-nous plutôt « La chauve-souris est l’équivalent dans les airs de la souris » que « Les chauves-souris sont l’équivalent dans les airs des souris » ?

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu qui que ce soit dire *est l'équivalent dans les airs de [...]* D'où vient cette tournure bizarre ?

Comment: "L'ilu est l'équivalent en eau d'un direhorse. Ils sont plus joueurs que les Skimwings."

Comment: https://forum.premiere.fr/Cinema/News-Cinema/Decouvrez-les-Tulkuns-Skimwings-et-llus-les-creatures-aquatiques-dAvatar-2

Comment: Je me suis inspiré de cette phrase pour écrire celle en titre.

Comment: La proposition se voulait un exemple seulement, sans égard à la vérité.

Comment: Il ne s'est pas foulé le journaliste de Télérama. Google et Deepl traduisent mieux que lui *water equivalent* dans la phrase *"The ilu is the water equivalent of a direhorse. They are more playful than skimwings."* qui est la phrase originale de Jon Landau. C'est "l'équivalent aquatique" et ton "équivalent dans les airs" aurait du être un "équivalent aérien", "volant", voire "volatile" alors que "dans les airs", pas top...

Comment: *It's not gonna fly* comme ils disent ;-)

Comment: Merci d’apporter cette correction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Réponse à la première question et  essai personnel d'explication du mystère  énoncé par la seconde*

1.

> Quelle est la différence entre
> « La chauve-souris est l’équivalent dans les airs de la souris. » et
> « Une chauve-souris est l’équivalent dans les airs d’une souris » ?

**a)** Ces formulations ne sont pas syntaxiquement très bonnes.

> Quelle est la différence entre
> « La chauve-souris est  dans les airs  l’équivalent de la souris. » et
> « Une chauve-souris est dans les airs l’équivalent d’une souris » ?

**b)** La différence est tout simplement que l'article défini en français sert à exprimer une notion générique, mais  l'article indéfini ne sert à cette fonction que de façon particulière ; il est parfois impossible de l'utiliser génériquement alors que l'article défini ne pose aucun problème, et de plus on ne l'utilise pas autant, ce qui résulte en sa force amoindrie dans sa fonction générique.

[image]

- <s>Un chat se trouve dans toute l'Asie.</s>
- Le chat se trouve dans toute l'Asie.

2. 

> Et pourquoi disons-nous plutôt « La chauve-souris est l’équivalent dans les airs de la souris » que « Les chauves-souris sont l’équivalent dans les airs des souris » ?

Cela semble  exact. Voici les ngrams pour « chien » et « chat ». Ils montrent ce fait.

[image]

[image]

Cependant, ce principe n'est pas sans exception selon [J.M. Kalmbach](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-defini.html#069) (Grammaire Étudiant Finnophone).

> Le nom avec ar­ti­cle dé­fi­ni peut donc dé­si­gner un grou­pe :
>
> • Les fran­çais seraient individualistes.
> • De nos jours, on dirait que les étudiants ont de moins en moins de temps pour étudier.
> •  Les Normands ont envahi l’An­gle­terre au XIe siècle.
> •  La rencontre entre les ouvriers et les patrons a été un échec.
>
> Dans ce cas, le singulier suffit à dé­si­gner tout les éléments du gen­re ou du grou­pe, mais ce moyen d’ex­pri­mer la gé­né­ri­cité est moins fré­quen­t que le pluriel, car il a une valeur gé­né­ra­li­san­te très forte :
>
> • Le fran­çais serait individualiste.
> • De nos jours, l’étudiant est sou­vent obligé de faire des petits boulots pour vivre convenablement.

L'article défini singulier aurait une plus grande force généralisante peut-être parce que l'utiliser dans ce but  n'entraîne pas l'ambigüité  d'une implication totale du groupe. Par exemple, dans la seconde phrase ci-dessous, il est possible de comprendre, bien que ça semble être du complet non-sens, que tous les chevaux en 1493 se sont trouvés sur le nouveau continent.

- Le cheval a fait son apparition sur le continent américain en 1493.
- Les chevaux ont fait leur  apparition sur le continent américain en 1493.

================================================================
***Réponse aux commentaires de user Antivlad ([commentaire 1 et suivants](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52075/quelle-est-la-diff%c3%a9rence-entre-la-chauve-souris-est-l-%c3%a9quivalent-dans-les-airs/52078?noredirect=1#comment108031_52078))***

1/ *Et donc, on pourrait aussi comprendre dans « Les Français sont individualistes » que tous les Français sont individualistes… De ce point de vue l’article défini pluriel aurait une valeur généralisante plus forte…car il impliquerait la totalité du groupe.*

Je pense qu'il faut comprendre que la « valeur généralisante » se situe non pas sur le plan d'une qualité intrinsèque de la méthode, en l'occurrence l'utilisation de l'article défini pluriel, mais qu'elle est  plutôt vérifiée en vertu d'un usage systématique que l'on en fait et que c'est finalement un élément subjectif de jugement. Personnellement je ne pense pas avoir généralisé plus extensivement lorsque j'ai dit « Le chat est un animal vivace. » que lorsque j'ai dit « Les chats sont des animaux vivaces. » ; je n'ai même pas l'impression que ce choix est plus effectif dans la communication de cette idée. Non, l'article défini pluriel a une valeur généralisante (subjective) moins forte : elle est moins forte que celle de l'article défini singulier, et elles sont toutes deux moins forte (objectivement) que celle de « tous/toutes les »; La totalité du groupe n'est impliqué que dans l'ensemble, il est parfois nécessaire de préciser dans la discussion le degré d'extension de cette généralité, sauf dans les discussion dans les sciences exactes, et cela qu'il s'agisse de l'une ou de l'autre des deux méthodes (article singulier ou pluriel) ; même lorsque  le locuteur  utilise « tous/toutes les » il est parfois enclin à ajouter un adverbe comme « absolument » ou un cc comme « sans exception ».

2/ *La phrase « L'article défini singulier aurait une plus grand force généralisante peut-être parce que l'utiliser dans ce but n'entraîne pas l'ambigüité d'une implication totale du groupe. » ne contient-elle pas une contradiction interne?*

Je vois que vous n'avez pas compris cette partie, et elle n'a peut-être pas tant de valeur, je suis loin d'avoir fini d'y penser. Lorsque j'ai écrit « n'entraîne pas l'ambigüité d'une implication totale du groupe », je ne pensais qu'à des séries de cas particulier ou l'espèce est confondue avec les représentants actuels ; le « groupe » est le groupe des représentants actuels (je dis bien que l'idée est saugrenue), mais elle « hante » le contexte sémantique. Il s'ensuit que selon ce concept de « force généralisante » en tant que moyen effectif de communication, l'idée de généralisation (qui reste la même) est imprimée plus nettement dans les esprits.

Néanmoins, dire que l'idée est absurde n'est pas généralisable, pas parfaitement ; l'exemple des Normands montre cela. Il n'est plus question de quelques éléments du groupe comme dans le cas des chevaux mais d'un nombre important de Normands qui se trouvaient en France. Il est possible qu'il ne faille plus parler de généricité dans ce cas, puisque en aucun cas on ne dira « Le Normand a envahi ».

3/ *Peut-être que je me méprends sur la signification de « grande force généralisante » mais à mon sens si la généralisation implique la totalité d’un groupe alors elle est nécessairement plus forte qu’une généralisation qui n’en implique qu’une partie. Il y aurait quelques clarifications à ajouter là-dessus.*

Oui, bien sûr ; mes commentaires précédent devraient suffire.

4/ *Peut-être cherchiez-vous à dire « L’article singulier serait plus employé parce que… »*

Non, mais je crois que c'est plus ou moins la même chose : une plus grand force généralisante ressentie entraine un emploi plus important et un emploi important pour la généralisation contribue à donner de la force à l'emploi.

5/ *Il serait bien aussi d’expliciter la nuance entre les termes « généralisation » et « généralisation plus forte ». Je crois que je mélange "valeur généralisante très forte" et "plus grande force généralisante", qui ne veulent probablement pas dire la même chose. Pourriez-vous s'il vous plaît préciser la différence entre ces deux termes dans votre réponse ?*

Cela a été fait ci-dessus ; « une valeur gé­né­ra­li­san­te très forte (ou plus forte) » et « une plus grande force généralisante » reviennent à la même chose ;  on parle de la même chose en tant que propriété (valeur) qui est celle de pouvoir agir avec une certaine force et de la nature de cette propriété qui est celle d'être une force.

En parlant de valeur linguistique, il est intéressant de considérer les remarques suivantes faites par Saussure.

> Quand on parle de la valeur d'un mot, on pense généralement et avant tout à la propriété qu'il a de représenter une idée, et c'est là en effet un des aspects de la valeur linguistique. Mais s'il en est ainsi, en quoi cette valeur diffère-t-elle de ce qu'on appelle la signification? Ces deux mots seraient-ils synonymes? Nous ne le croyons pas, bien que la confusion soit facile, d'autant qu'elle est provoquée, moins par l'analogie des termes que par la délicatesse de la distinction qu'ils marquent. Sauss.1916, p. 158.

6/ Pour traiter de ce que dit ChatGPT :

> En résumé, il semblerait que le choix entre l'article défini singulier et le pluriel dans ce contexte dépend de l'intention de l'auteur en ce qui concerne la portée généralisante de l'assertion faite. L'article défini singulier a une valeur généralisante très forte, c'est-à-dire qu'il sous-entend que la caractéristique ou qualité mentionnée s'applique à l'ensemble du groupe ou de la catégorie en question. A l'inverse, l'utilisation du pluriel permet d'éviter cette implication totale et laisse une certaine marge de manœuvre quant à l'étendue de la généralisation.

> "Par exemple, si l'on dit "le français est individualiste", cela implique que la qualité d'individualiste s'applique à l'ensemble des personnes considérées comme françaises. Si l'on utilise plutôt l'article défini pluriel "les" dans cette phrase, cela signifie que l'on parle de plusieurs personnes considérées comme françaises, mais pas nécessairement de l'ensemble des personnes de cette nationalité."

> Oui, c'est exact. Il semble que la dernière partie du texte contredit la première. Dans la première partie, l'auteur suggère que l'article défini singulier a une force généralisante plus grande que celle de l'article défini pluriel, alors que dans la seconde partie, il soutient le contraire, c'est-à-dire que l'article défini pluriel a une force généralisante plus grande que celle de l'article défini singulier.

> Cette contradiction peut être due à une erreur ou à un manque de clarté dans la rédaction du texte. Il est important de vérifier les informations et les arguments présentés dans un texte avant de les utiliser, afin de s'assurer de leur exactitude et de leur pertinence.

Je ne perçois pas cette différence. Puisque il existe une prédilection pour utiliser l'article pluriel dans ces cas où une moindre force généralisante (dans le sens objectif) serait souhaitable, pourquoi préfère-t-on l'utiliser quand même lorsque la généralisation est absolue, comme dans le cas suivant ?

- Les boulangers, en France, sont des gens qui vivent la nuit. (*boulanger traditionnel dans un passé récent*)

Il est vrai que l'on dira peu « Le boulanger, en France, est une personne qui vit la nuit. » ; pourquoi existe-t-il cette contradiction du principe ?

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141919/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-quelle-est-la-difference-entrela-chauve-souris-es). I have also expunged the Chat-GPT section as not even worthy of comment.

Comment: @LukeSawczak The value of ChatGPT might not be very great, I don't know, but what's been selected from it is tantamount to the OP's opinion at the time of the discussion, and it serves my discussion and the point I finally make; moreover this opinion is essentially that of other grammarians; so I think it should remain.

Comment: Then it can be found in whichever other grammarians' text the ChatGPT output is loosely based on and credited.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Since I removed from the text the reference "ChatGPT", there shouldn't be any problem; The OP has no obligation to give references for opinions he/she has made his/hers.

Comment: A rose by any other name is still a rose...

Comment: @LukeSawczak Strange,  I read that two or three days ago (something from Shakespeare); yes, not naming the source does make the idea better, but in order to dispel the erroneous thinking about something you have to take that something apart and show what's wrong with it, not that I did that thouroughly in this case, but it is a beginning.

Comment: Indeed, from Romeo & Juliet. I was thinking of modifying it to bramble but the point is the same without the extra barb. Anyhow, I agree with that motivation enough to leave the matter be, but I will add the identification back.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I saw an error in my last comment: read "not naming the source does NOT  make the idea better".

Comment: I figured that was the intention :)

Comment: À mon avis les réponses ne doivent pas servir d'ardoise où l'on commente tous les commentaires. Et tous les commentaires ne demandent pas d'être discutés dans une réponse. Et une réponse doit être une réponse, pas une ébauche qui se raffine au fur et à mesure qu'on descend dans sa lecture ou qui court-circuite le suivi des modifs. À mon avis l'énoncé de ChatGPT pouvait rester dans un commentaire et on pouvait y faire allusion en incluant au besoin un lien (url, copier-coller à partir du _timestamp_ du commentaire) dans la réponse vers le commentaire. On peut aussi produire plus d'une réponse.

Comment: L'élément 6) débute par "Pour traiter de ce que dit ChatGPT :" Et le deuxième paragraphe est entre guillemets. Le résultat est qu'on ne sait pas qui rédige ces paragraphes, et si le deuxième est ce que dit LPH en réponse au verbiage de ChatGPT, et alors pourquoi le troisième débuterait par "Oui c'est exact" et à quelle contradiction de quel texte ça réfère etc. En fin de compte il aurait peut-être été mieux de répondre à une abstraction de ce que dit ChatGPT qu'à ses paroles directement. Le tout est un bon exemple du fouillis qu'entraîne l'usage de ce robot de plagiat neuronal.

Answer (score 1):

*La chauve-souris* ici désigne une *espèce*, plutôt qu'un animal (*un chauve-souris*) ou un groupe d'animaux (*les/des chauve-souris*).

En principe, cet usage est conforme aux règles de grammaire déjà citées dans la réponse de @LPH, mais je pense que dans le cas des espèces l'application de ces règles est particulièrement transparente.

Comment: La vérification systématique de l'orthographe dans un dictionnaire permet d'éviter les fautes d'orthographes élémentaires et permet aussi d'apprendre ces orthographes ; il est nécessaire, autant que possible de fournir des références pour les raisons que l'on donne en explication.

Comment: @LPH pourriez-vous me donner des conseils pratiques concernant *la vérification systématique*: s'agit-il de vérifier chaque mot chaque fois quand j'écris quelque chose, quelles que soient l'occasion et la longueur du texte, ou l'utilisation de spellcheck ou quelque chose d'autre ? Quelle méthode utilisez-vous dans votre propre pratique pédagogique ou votre apprentissage de langues étrangères ?

Comment: Tout simplement, en écrivant, lorsque vous avez un doute et tant que le doute persiste, vérifiez ; c'est ce à quoi je m'astreins moi-même ; bien sûr, s'il y a un programme qui montre une forme correcte, il n'y a qu'à se rabattre sur le programme. De plus, je n'avais pas pensé à ça, mais les orthographes des verbes, qui ne sont pas si élémentaires, se vérifient au moyen d'une table des conjugaisons, comme [celle-ci](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/astreindre.html), par exemple ; en cherchant vous en trouverez d'autres.

Comment: @LPH Je parle plutôt de la quantité de travail qu'une telle vérification implique - c'est une chose de le faire comme un devoir pour une classe de français, mais c'est une autre chose quand vous devez utiliser une langue dans votre vie quotidienne (y compris professionnelle.) Bien sûr, on pourrait toujours limiter l'utilisation de langue au minimum nécessaire, ce qui ne me paraisse pas comme une meilleure solution.

Comment: C'est exact, c'est beaucoup de travail, mais si vous ne le faites pas votre progrès reste lent et vous prenez de mauvaises habitudes. De plus, l'un des principes concernant les échanges sur ce site est de préserver à la langue de tous une forme qui reflète les meilleurs standards. Qui lit de la langue qui mal écrite apprend à écrire mal, et il n'y a pas que des érudits sur le site FSE ; nous devons donc aux débutants cet effort de leur présenter la meilleure forme possible du langage. Enfin, il faut éviter à ceux qui corrigent d'avoir à faire un travail que l'auteur peut faire lui-même. (1/2)

Comment: Bien vous mettre en tête que le plus tôt vous vous imposez cette contrainte le plus tôt vous pourrez l'abandonner, ou tout au moins le plus tôt vous n'aurez plus à en souffrir tant ; vous en aurez de moins en moins besoin et votre écriture aura toujours été correcte, même si plus lente au début. (2/2)

Comment: @LPH merci pour les conseils et l'encouragement. Je pense qu'effectivement j'ai pas mal des mauvaises habitudes, car j'apprends/parle français depuis assez longtemps. J'essaye de faire mon mieux.

Comment: Une technique de plus pour vérifier des expressions : « pas mal des mauvaises » n'est pas correct, mais il est difficile de savoir. Il y a un moyen de vérifier rapidement, c'est de faire une recherche Google : [pas mal des mauvaises,pas mal de mauvaises](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pas+mal+des+mauvaises%2Cpas+mal+de+mauvaises&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3).